# What is wrong in this post code

Tags: jquery

```
$.post(
  "login.php", 
  { user: id, pass: ps, action: 'd56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da" },
  function(data){   
    var status = ($.evalJSON(data).oc);
    msgbox($.evalJSON(data).title,$.evalJSON(data).msg,status);
    if(status==1) { window.location = $.evalJSON(data).page; }
    } 
  );
```

Comment: You should only call `evalJSON` once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is the quote, see the ending quote here 'd56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da"

Correction 'd56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da'

Comment: Sometimes you get stuck and then figure out its the most simplest thing in the world - :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a quote mismatch.

Change it to

```
$.post(
  "login.php", 
  { user: id, pass: ps, action: 'd56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da' },
  function(data){   
    var status = ($.evalJSON(data).oc);
    msgbox($.evalJSON(data).title,$.evalJSON(data).msg,status);
    if(status==1) { window.location = $.evalJSON(data).page; }
    } 
  );
```

Also, Javascript has no `msgbox` function.  Change it to `alert` and pass only one parameter.  (Unless its a function you wrote yourself)

Answer (score 3):

To start,

```
'd56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da"
```

should be

```
"d56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da"
```